# Echo new line and string beginning \t

Tags: bash, quoting, echo

Sure, echo -e can be used so that \n is understood as a new line. The problem is when I want to echo something beginning with \t e.g. "\test".

So let's say I want to perform `echo -e "test\n\\test"`. I expect this to output:

> ```
> test
> \test
> ```

But instead outputs:

> ```
> test
>   est
> ```

The `\\t` is being interpreted as a tab instead of a literal \t. Is there a clean workaround for this issue?

Comment: Use single quotes and avoid `echo`. `printf 'test\n\\test\n'` or `printf 'test\n%s\n' '\test'`.

Comment: Sure, thanks. Is an echo solution possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo -e "\\t"
```

passes `\t` to `echo` because backslash is special inside double-quotes in `bash`. It serves as an *escaping* (quoting) operator. In `\\`, it escapes itself.

You can either do:

```
echo -e "\\\\t"
```

for `echo` to be passed `\\t` (`echo -e "\\\t"` would also do), or you could use single quotes within which `\` is not special:

```
echo -e '\t'
```

Now, [`echo` is a very unportable command](/q/65803). Even in `bash`, its behaviour can depend on the environment. I'd would advise to avoid it and use `printf` instead, with which you can do:

```
printf 'test\n\\test\n'
```

Or even decide which parts undergo those escape sequence expansions:

```
printf 'test\n%s\n' '\test'
```

Or:

```
printf '%b%s\n' 'test\n' '\test'
```

`%b` understands the same escape sequences as `echo` (some `echo`s), while the first argument to `printf`, the format, also understands sequences, but in a slightly different way than `echo` (more like what is done in other languages). In any case `\n` is understood by both.

Answer (score 1):

This is not in accordance with manual for the command, but man itself states point 1:

1. Echo depends on your shell (and there are other reasons sometimes to avoid it, like piping).
2. Stéphane's comment is not a bad way to go: `printf` it.
3. `echo` solution `echo -e "a\na\ta"` (double quotes, read up on what they do though if you want to expand that code for something more) and tests:

`

```
➜  ~ echo -e a \n a \ta
a n a ta
➜  ~ echo -e "a \n a \ta"
a 
 a  a
➜  ~ echo -e "a\na\ta"   
a
a   a
➜  ~ bash                
T420s:~$ echo -e "a\na\ta"
a
a   a
T420s:~$ echo -e a\na\ta
anata
T420s:~$ echo a\na\ta
anata
T420s:~$ echo "a\na\ta"
a\na\ta
T420s:~$
```

First shell is ZSH.

Answer (score 0):

The shell snippet `"test\n\\test"` expands to the string `test\n\test`, because a backslash inside double quotes causes the next character to be interpreted literally if the next character is one of `` "$\` `` and otherwise the backslash itself is interpreted literally. Then `echo -e` replaces `\n` with a newline and `\t` with a tab.

Avoid double quotes to quote literal text. Use single quotes instead: they have simpler rules — everything inside single quotes is interpreted literally is a single quote. If you choose to use double quotes, don't use backslashes that are not followed by a character that it would quote — if you want a backslash inside double quotes, use `\\`.

```
echo -e 'test\n\\test'
echo -e "test\\n\\\\test"
```