# Why doesn't printf escape newlines?

Tags: bash, newlines, printf

```
$ printf "hi"
hi$ printf "hi\n"
hi
$ printf "hi\\n"
hi
```

Why doesn't the last line print `hi\n`?

Comment: So this is undefined behaviour?

Comment: That's odd. I though when enclosed in single quotes everything took on a literal value. I would have expected printf 'hi\n' to print hi\n

Comment: @jesse_b Other characters can be used in the format string as long as it is constant. Assuming that this is based off of the behavior of C's `printf` (which is almost surely true), `printf "hi\\n"` is perfectly valid.

Comment: @jesse_b [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) does not say something about anything similar to `printf "hi\\n"` being invalid.

Comment: @jesse_b `printf` with a single argument is perfecty valid. The format string can contain other characters and does not need to include any format specifiers. The OP's problem has to do with how the argument is escaped by the shell, not with the way `printf` is being used.

Comment: @Grodriguez: Technically correct but if OP just used printf correctly there would be no issue ;).  There is also technically nothing wrong with using unquotted variables, parsing ls, and doing `rm -rf *` (in a perfect world), but if you want to avoid unexpected behavior you should just do things properly every time.

Comment: Related (on [ubuntu.se]): [Why don't “echo -e” commands seem to produce the right output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1169851/why-dont-echo-e-commands-seem-to-produce-the-right-output)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is nothing to do with `printf`, and everything to do with *the argument that you have given to `printf`*.

In a double-quoted string, the shell turns `\\` into `\`.  So the argument that you have given to `printf` is actually `hi\n`, which of course `printf` then performs *its own* escape sequence processing on.

In a double-quoted string, the escaping done through `\` by the shell is specifically limited to affecting the ␊, `\`, `` ` ``, `$`, and `"` characters.  You will find that `\n` gets passed to `printf` as-is.  So the argument that you have given to `printf` is actually `hi\n` *again*.

Be careful about putting escape sequences into the format string for `printf`.  *Only some* have defined meanings in the *Single Unix Specification*.  `\n` is defined, but `\c` is actually not, for example.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/359510/5132
- [POSIX Shell: inside of double-quotes, are there cases where `\` fails to escape `$`, ```, `"`, `\` or `<newline>`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/492880/5132)
- [Why is a single backslash shown when using quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/398646/5132)
- [Echo new line and string beginning \t](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/348786/5132)
- [Why does dash expand \\\\ differently to bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321422/5132)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558665/5132

Comment: In other words, you need to double-escape your backlashes because they're going through two rounds of interpolation, the shell's and then printf's. `printf "hi\\\\n"` will print the single literal backslash.

Comment: It's usually simplest to put the format string in single quotes. That prevents all escape character processing by the shell, and leaves it to `printf`. The exception would be if you want to have a literal single quote in the format string.

Comment: @BallpointBen It's enough with 3 backslashes as the shell would leave the third untouched. To the shell, `\n` is the same as `\\n`, so `\\\n` is the same as `\\\\n`. Honestly, it's better to just use single-quotes to avoid this shell behaviour.

Comment: @ilkkachu It seems it does: *You will find that ```\n``` gets passed to printf as-is.*

Comment: @JdeBP The sequence `\c` **is** defined ([in POSIX point 7](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_13)) when used with the `%b` conversion specifier.

Comment: In bash and zsh and when csh-style history substitution is enabled, backslash within double quotes also escapes `!` (or whatever the first character of `$histchars` is), but in the case of `bash`, the backslash is not removed. (`echo -E "\!foo"` still outputs `\!foo` in `bash` even though backslash served its purpose at disabling history substitution)

Comment: @Isaac, ah right, it's just unclearly written.

Answer (score 17):

Within double quotes, `\\n` is an escaped (quoted) backslash followed by a `n`.  This is given to `printf` as `\n` and `printf` will output a newline.

Within double quotes (still), `\n` is the string `\n`. Again, `printf` receives a `\n` string and will print a newline.

Within double quotes, backslash is special *only* when preceding another backslash, a newline, or any of `$`, `` ` `` or `"`.  "Special" means that it removes the special meaning of the next character.  If a backslash precedes any other character (`n` for example), then it's just a backslash character.

This is explained in [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_03).

To print `\n` in a `printf` format string, use `printf '\\n'` or `printf "\\\\n"`, or use `printf '%s' '\n'`

In general, the `printf` format string should be single quoted and any variable data should be given as additional arguments to be inserted into the format string:

```
printf 'This is how you write a newline: %s\n' '\n'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103978/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-why-doesnt-printf-escape-newlines).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets add another point of view.

There are two levels of interpretation here at play. One is the shell, the other is the command (in this case `printf`) interpretation of the arguments received.

**Inside double quotes** The shell will leave alone most of the sequences backslash-character, this is the common result:

```
$ printf '%s\n'    "\a \b \c \d ... \z     \$ \` \\ "
\a \b \c \d ... \z     $ ` \
```

**Except** with `$`, `` ` ``, and `\` which, being especial to the shell, get their `\` removed.

So, testing both the strings you used (and others), we get:

```
$ printf '%s\n'     "hi\n"     "hi\\n"    "hi\\\n"    "hi\\\\n"    "hi\\\\\n"
hi\n
hi\n
hi\\n
hi\\n
hi\\\n
```

The shell converts pairs of `\\` to one `\`. And leaves alone `\n` as `\n`.

Now, `printf` has an special relation to the first argument, it is explicitly set to be `the format`. In the format argument, some characters are special (to printf), for example: valid sequences that start with a `%` character **and** some [sequences of backslash-character](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_13) like:

```
\\  \a  \b  \f  \n  \r  \t  \v  and the special \ddd
```

So, the string `\n` generates a newline but a `\\n` don't:

```
$ printf "    hi\n    hi\\n    hi\\\n   hi\\\\n"; echo
hi
hi
hi\n   hi\n
```